# MAUI: Issue with deleteing the last item from ObservableCollection

Tags: maui, observablecollection

I am using an 'ObservableCollection' saving comments. When I delete a comment, I will fetch the deleted comment id and delete that comment from the 'ObservableCollection'.

My Problem is if I delete the last comment all the previous comments are vanishing from the UI and showing only the initial comment. When I reopen the page or delete any other comment the vanished previous comments are coming back.

**My Code:**

```
foreach (var item in customerCommentList)
{
    if (item.parentComment.supportItemComments.commentId == deleteCommentId)
    {
        customerCommentList.Remove(item);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here `customerCommentList` is the collection and from that I removing the data. Is there any issue in deleting an item from the collection? Is there any known issue in net 7.0?

Screen recorder video uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WyhqndnmqgCO9hQdpIRwBon1ESsIzr_a/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FFoCUGLABbyB1NszjefHTeDRxICG8IAV/view?usp=sharing) to understand the issue.

**UPDATE**

I have created a more optimized demo with more findings and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZgPzCQRjrmigPjEAbiJmD9pTyosnmgew/view?usp=sharing).

On this demo I have added 2 pages, one is `CommentPage` and the other one is `MainPage`. On both pages I have used the same logic to show the items on the UI and delete an item from UI. On `MainPage` everything is working fine and on `CommentsPage` I am facing the same issues. On both the pages the UI is different, so I think the issue is related to the UI layouts. Unfortunately I can't trigger it out.

I suspect it is due to calling the functions from background thread, so I verified that and on both background thread and main UI thread the same issue is there.

Comment: Can you provide us how you use your ObservableCollection in your view ? Especially, are you using it in a [RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-8.0) ?

Comment: I am using `listview` to show the items on the UI and I set the observable collection as the `itemsource` of `listview`. `commentlistview.ItemsSource = customerCommentList;`

Comment: Then maybe trying nesting your ListView in a RefreshView, and triggering the refreshing when you delete your item could do the trick

Comment: I didn't work with RefreshView, so what property of RefreshView I neeed to trigger after deleting an item?

Comment: You need to set IsRefreshing to true, then it'll call the RefreshCommand where you can refresh your data, Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-8.0) for an example implementation.

Comment: @GChapX After deleting I added the above `Itemsource` line to refresh the data, but same effect. If we add the RefreshCommand of RefreshView, what code I need to put there?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you're handling your comment deletion ?

Comment: @GChapX I have created a demo project and added the same logic on it and on demo it is working fine. But on the main project this logic breaks, could you plesae check the demo https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RokDornqx6OPn14enixYikN5KjgSDXol/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @GChapX Can you show me how we need to add refreshview with the demo codes?

Comment: You could  add a breakpoint at the ```customerCommentList.Remove(item);``` to check if this *Delete Command* only execute one time. Or it might be a layout issue.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT When deleting only the selected comment is removing from collection because I have printed the count of collection and it is correct.

Comment: Could you share the relevant code about how you manage the layout  for the main project?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT
I have created a real demo and uploaded here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vMepnmvZcJy44BY_MENjatDesbtQ11Go/view?usp=sharing  Could you please check that? Click on the last comment and check the UI, a few comments are vanishing from the UI. But If u reopen you can see the remaining comments on the UI. Click on the comment to see the delete option.

Comment: When i delete the item, everything seems okay. (After I delete the item, i cannot fetch the data again). I don't know if I missed anything. And in your project, why do you set the AbsoluteLayout to rotate 180?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Please try to delete the last item. At that time the some of the top items are vanishing from the UI. If you delete the middle items, no issues. Could you try like that? I have added the comments again. I need to show few icons on top of the listview, for that I am using absolutelayout and to reverse the listview I am using the rotate feature.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I have created a more optimized demo and uploaded here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzqaI72dHoxurdJzogzuFs6rRuxGEVCF/view This demo has the dummy data and if u delete any middle item , the items after that is vanishing from the UI. Could you please check that, I am stuck on this around a week.

Comment: Okay I just tried your new demo on iOS with no issue. I will try on Android later.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I have edited the question with new findings and a new demo. Could you please check that.

Comment: This issue happens only on Android (cannot reproduce on iOS). Finally, after much debuggings, I found that because you use ```CachingStrategy```. So just set ```CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"``` that makes the issue disappear on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue on Android (But work fine on iOS).

The only difference between the `CommentPage` and the `MainPage` is the [**Caching strategy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#caching-strategy), which is used to improve performance.

The default value of this property is `RetainElement`. So, you just change the value for the ListView in `CommentPage` which makes the issue disappear.

```
<ListView
    ...
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    SeparatorColor="#cecece"
    SelectionMode="None"
    HasUnevenRows="True">
```

Another suggestion is that you could use [**CollectionView**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-8.0) instead of **ListView**, as aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView. Tested with no issue on **CollectionView**.

Comment: I already used `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` before this issue and that also makes some issues with listing the comments. I didn't remember what it is exactly, I need to check that again. Now the delete issue is resolved with this.

Comment: Is collectionview has `pulldownrefresh` and `itemappearing` features like listview? I need these 2 features for listing comments. When I check for these 2 I didn't found that.

Comment: You could try a [RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-8.0). Also see this tutorial : [Pull-To-Refresh, EmptyView and Layouts with CollectionView - .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=invsT4ST1SI)

Comment: Also here is the official doc: [Pull to refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#pull-to-refresh) and  [Load data incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#load-data-incrementally).